# Count words and letters by using LetterCounts and WordCount

Tags: string-manipulation

How can I count letters and words in the following "text", by using
`LetterCounts` and `WordCount`?

```
 text = {"რომელმან", "შექმნა", "სამყარო", "ძალითა", "მით", "ძლიერითა", 
"ზეგარდმო", "არსნი", "სულითა", "ყვნა", "ზეცით", "მონაბერითა", 
"ჩვენ", "კაცთა", "მოგვცა", "ქვეყანა", "გვაქვს", "უთვალავი", 
"ფერითა", "მისგან", "არს", "ყოვლი", "ხელმწიფე", "სახითა", "მის", 
"მიერითა"}
```

I tried:

```
LetterCounts[text]
WordCount[text]
```

but that doesn't work.

When I remove the quotes from `text` (by hand), then `WordCount` works, but `LetterCounts` still doesn't.

Comment: Try `LetterCounts[StringRiffle[text]]`; as noted in the docs, you need to give a string and not a list of strings.

Comment: Both `LetterCounts` and `WordCount` want a single string, not a list, as its argument.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, both works perfectly  `LetterCounts[StringRiffle[text]]` `WordCount[StringRiffle[text]]`

Comment: Can you answer your own question, then?

Comment: @J.M. yes, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

I use code from J.M comment, and it works perfectly

```
text = {"რომელმან", "შექმნა", "სამყარო", "ძალითა", "მით", "ძლიერითა", 
"ზეგარდმო", "არსნი", "სულითა", "ყვნა", "ზეცით", "მონაბერითა", 
"ჩვენ", "კაცთა", "მოგვცა", "ქვეყანა", "გვაქვს", "უთვალავი", 
"ფერითა", "მისგან", "არს", "ყოვლი", "ხელმწიფე", "სახითა", "მის", 
"მიერითა"}

LetterCounts[StringRiffle[text]]
WordCount[StringRiffle[text]]
```

[image]